# JSON encode outputting result

Tags: php

This is my php code

```
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product");
    $bla = array();
    $numOfRows= mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($numOfRows >0)
    { while ($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            //$productID=$rows["id"];
            $bla[]=$rows;

    //echo '<p class="image"><img style="border: " src="images/'.$productID.'.jpg" width="154" height="137"/></p>';
    echo json_encode($bla);
        }

        }
```

the output result is as follows

[{"id":"2","title":"iPhone 5","price":"500","category":"Mobile ","description":"APPLE","date_added":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","date_update":"0000-00-00"}]

[{"id":"2","title":"iPhone 5","price":"500","category":"Mobile ","description":"APPLE","date_added":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","date_update":"0000-00-00"},
{"id":"41","title":"samsung S3","price":"100","category":"Mobile ","description":"asda","date_added":"2013-03-10 21:43:12","date_update":"2013-03-10"}]

as you can see the product id 2 is repeated. how can I remove this? I want only the second array to be shown!! In my database system I DO NOT have repeated data I have no idea where this is coming from please help

Comment: I suggest you improve your indentation, to avoid this kind of errors (see Galen's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the echo json_encode( $bla ) in the loop. Move it out.

```
if ($numOfRows >0)
{ while ($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $bla[]=$rows;
    }
    echo json_encode($bla);
}
```